# On Mac OS programming, what is default? nonatomic or atomic?

Tags: objective-c

```
@property ( atomic, assign ) Object *object1;
@property ( nonatomic, assign ) Object *object2;
```

What is default setting?
I know that 'nonatomic' is default setting on iPhone programming.

On the Mac programming? Is that the same?

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "default"? If you don't specify `atomic` or `nonatomic`, the property will be assumed to be atomic regardless of platform.

Comment: @Seongeon: next time, first check [the Objective-C documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW28).

Comment: @outis Ok. I'll do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Atomic vs nonatomic properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties (the answer there covers significantly more ground, too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, declared property accessors are atomic in both iOS and Mac OS. There is no `atomic` keyword.

Comment: @KennyTM Really? The documentation says otherwise.

Comment: @KennyTM And Clang/LLVM 1.6 gives syntax error (Unknown property attribute 'atomic').

Comment: Your answer is a little obsolete. There is atomic keyword now.