# iOS 7: Property not found on object of type

Tags: ios

I have been following Apple's [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html) guide and have run into a problem. I'm not a newbie developer but I am new to iOS development and I can't see why I'm going wrong.

I have a file called STRAddTodoViewController.h which contains the following

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "STRTodo.h"

@interface STRAddTodoViewController : UIViewController
@property STRTodo *todoItem;
@end
```

And in my STRTodosViewController.m I have:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    STRAddTodoViewController *addTodo = [segue sourceViewController];
    STRTodo *item = addTodo.todoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.todos addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an error of:

```
Property 'todoItem' not found on object of type 'STRAddTodoViewController *'
```

For some reason, my public variable in STRAddTodoViewController isn't getting picked up in my other controller and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any clues?

**EDIT:** Massive apologies everyone, seems like I had two copies of STRAddTodoViewController in my project and it was reading the old one when it was building. Such a simple mistake and I feel like a massive idiot now, but thanks to everyone who helped me out.

Comment: Nothing jumps at me right away. Just to make sure, you did `#import` the h file, right?

Comment: @LeoNatan Yep, STRTodosViewController.h has #import "STRAddTodoViewController.h" and #import "STRTodo.h"

Comment: If you found a solution, please answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `#import "STRTodo.h"` by `@class STRTodo;` in your `STRAddTodoViewController.h` header file and add `#import "STRTodo.h"` in your `STRAddTodoViewController.m` implementation file.

Because if you already `#import "STRTodo.h"` and `#import "STRAddTodoViewController.h"` in your `STRTodoViewController.h` header file, compiler founds too much `#import "STRTodo.h"` and gets confused.

Does it helps ?

Comment: No luck unfortunately, I stripped back all the #import's to the bare minimum too and it still has the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have:
`@property STRTodo *todoItem;`
This means that STRTodo is indeed a class. Your property requires more identifiers.
`@property (nonatomic, strong) STRTodo *totoItem;`

In addition to this, in your `-(id) init` method, you should also instantiate the property.

```
- (id) init{
    if (self = [super init]{
        self.todoItem = [[STRTodo alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Nevermind, it seems you have found your solution.

Comment: The `nonatomic` and `strong` modifiers are not required.

Comment: That would be good to know. I have wasted a lot of time typing then!

Comment: Just remember that atomic properties (the default) are slower than nonatomic, so keep typing at least that.

Comment: A post referencing that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5024424/757485. So they are indeed not required here ;-)